# Plot in python after crosstab merge

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, seaborn, crosstab

I'd like to plot my `DataFrame`. I had this DF first:

```
id|project|categories|rating 
1 | a     | A        | 1
1 | a     | B        | 1
1 | a     | C        | 2
1 | b     | A        | 1
1 | b     | B        | 1
2 | c     | A        | 1
2 | c     | B        | 2
```

used this code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(...)
(df.groupby('id').project.nunique().reset_index()
   .merge(pd.crosstab(df.id, df.categories).reset_index()))
```

and now got this `DataFrame`:

```
id | project | A | B | C |
 1 | 2       | 2 | 2 | 1 |
 2 | 1       | 1 | 1 | 0 |
```

Now I'd like to plot the DF. I want to show, if the number of projects depends on how many categories are affected, or which categories are affected. I know how to visualize dataframes, but after crosstab and merging, it is not working as usual

Comment: What do you mean by `it is not working as usual`? What code did you try? Did you get any error?

Comment: I have fixed the code enhancement and added import and a stub for ``df`` creation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reproduced your data using below code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2,],\
                  'project': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c'],\
                  'categories': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B'],\
                  'rating': [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2]})
```

Now data looks like this

```
  categories  id project  rating
0          A   1       a       1
1          B   1       a       1
2          C   1       a       2
3          A   1       b       1
4          B   1       b       1
5          A   2       c       1
6          B   2       c       2
```

If you want to plot 'category count' as a function of 'project count' it looks like this.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# this line is your code
df2 = df.groupby('id').project.nunique().reset_index().merge(pd.crosstab(df.id, df.categories).reset_index())

plt.scatter(df2.project, df2.A, label='A', alpha=0.5)
plt.scatter(df2.project, df2.B, label='B', alpha=0.5)
plt.scatter(df2.project, df2.C, label='C', alpha=0.5)

plt.xlabel('project count')
plt.ylabel('category count')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

And you will get this

[image]

Comment: I've tried this, but I get an error message: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'A'. Any idea why?

Comment: i renamed the columns, because I had not A, B, C,... but 1,2,3 as column names. The DF was just an example. After changing the column name I get this error message. But I cannot call the columns while they are numbers, like df2.1 , or do I have to call it otherwise then?

Comment: You can access columns by df2[1] (if int) or df2['1'] (if string)

Comment: one more question, is there an opportunity to ignore the "0" in categories, in the visualization?

Comment: If you want to show only >=
1 of y values, add `plt.ylim(bottom=1)` before `plt.show()`